# How do I scroll through pictures on a Nikon D7100?

Tags: nikon, nikon-d7100

I just moved to a Nikon D7100. On my previous camera (D40X), I used to be able to press playback, then use the aperture/speed dial/wheel to scroll quickly through pictures in playback mode. I can't figure out how to do it on the D7100 (my friend has a D7000 and it works perfectly on his). On mine, when I scroll, nothing happens.. Do you know how to on this model?

Comment: Is there more than 1 picture on the card? It may sound like a silly question, but it did fool the salesperson in a camera shop i went to recently

Comment: Thanks for the thread. After reading all 384 pages of the user manual, I read over it without catching it. Really learned nothing new but found this answer here. I should have done it in the first place. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the back of the camera, there is a dial like this:

[image]

Use the arrows to scroll back and forth through your images, after pressing the playback button.  You can press up/down to scroll through additional information about an image (view histogram etc)

This is on page 35 of your [manual](http://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/en/products/27/D7100.html)

Edit: on page 257 of the manual, it says about custom menu f5 (Customize Command Dials):  if it is set to Off, then the multi-selector (that I described above) is used to scroll through images.  If set to On, then the aperture dial can be used.

So try going into custom menu, item f5 to On, and it may work as you expected.  It has other side effects which you can read in the manual

Comment: Thanks, I know of what you said. But what I was asking was if the aperture/speed dial/wheel can be used as in other models (it's much faster than the direction arrow buttons)?

Comment: Ok, added further info.

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried it and it worked perfectly!!